# auto filter not working

Tags: vba, excel

i have a code that has a command button which retrieves its records from an external file.
every time the command button is clicked it will delete all the records and paste again. however it allows the user input for records with "OFM","KH" and "Collar & Cuff" hence it would not delete these rows.

But, my autofilter code is not working properly as it still deletes the rows with "OFM" and "KH""

```
 Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter 
 field:=1, Criteria1:="<>OFM", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>KH"
```

the code:

```
Sub July()
Dim arr, c, b(), n&
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("July 2018").Range("A4").AutoFilter
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\sophia.tan\Desktop\MasterPlanData.xlsx", 0, 1
arr = Sheets("Excel").UsedRange
ActiveWorkbook.Close 0
c = Array(0, 2, 13, 14, 7, 8, 11, 1, 9, 10, 16, 17, 20, 22, 15, 30, 27, 28, 
29, 3, 4, 39)
d = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 23)
ReDim b(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 23)

For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
If arr(i, 13) >= DateSerial(Year:=2018, Month:=7, Day:=1) And arr(i, 12) <= 
DateSerial(Year:=2018, Month:=7, Day:=31) Then
    n = n + 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(c)
        b(n, d(j)) = arr(i, c(j))
     Next
 End If
Next


With Worksheets("July 2018")

.Range("A4:W" & 
Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter 
field:=13, Criteria1:="<>Collar & Cuff"
.Range("A4:W" & 
Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter 
field:=1, Criteria1:="<>OFM", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>KH"
.Range("A4:W" & Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 
0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
.Range("A4:W" & Rows.Count).Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)) = b
.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
.Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("G3"), order1:=xlAscending, 
Header:=xlYes
.Range("A4").Select
End With
Call Fabrication
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you filtering the xlCellTypeVisible cells? AutoFilter is cleared above this.

Comment: @Jeeped Maybe he does not realize that hiding rows doesn't prevent them from being processed?

Comment: @jeeped but even if the cells are not hidden, it is still deleted

Answer (score 1):

Your two-criteria-for-one-field AutoFilter logic is flawed. When something is not *KH* it can be *OFM* and when something is not *OFM* it can be *KH*. I believe you want to filter for not *KH* **and**  not *OFM*.

tldr;

You need xlAnd, not xlOr.

```
'...

With Worksheets("July 2018")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A4").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>Collar & Cuff"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>OFM", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>KH"   '<~~ THIS RIGHT HERE
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
            End If
        End With
        .Cells.Sort key1:=.Columns("G"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    '...
    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    .Range("A4").Select
End With
```

Comment: where does this code fit in: .Range("A4:W" & Rows.Count).Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)) = b          i have tried to add it in but it copies over additional data which are incorrect

Comment: I'm guessing it goes after the .ClearContents code line just as it does in your original code. TBH, I could never figure out what you were trying to do with it so I just fixed your original question about .AutoFilter. BTW, it can be shortened to .Range("A4").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)) = b since you are resizing in any event.

Comment: I added it after the .ClearContents and it could not copy the retrieved data. I tried to add it before the sorting code and it was able to copy over but the auto filter could not work.